# How to transform CSV to JSON data on Node JS

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, csv, ibm-cloud

I am using IBM Bluemix to make a web service for a school project.

I need to transform the `.csv` data I have in a directory in my computer into a `.json` file, so I can manipulate this information.

I am using the `fast-csv` package for Node JS, but I am having trouble with the code.

In the end of my `.js` file, there is a piece of code that is supposed to get the `.csv` file and convert it to JSON. I obtained it in the `fast-csv` documentation webpage.

When I run it, nothing happens and I can't fin out why. How can I check if the code is really getting the `.csv` file and transforming it into a `.json` one?

The `Cambio.csv` file is in the same directory of my `.js` one.

```js
// Hello.
//
// This is JSHint, a tool that helps to detect errors and potential
// problems in your JavaScript code.
//
// To start, simply enter some JavaScript anywhere on this page. Your
// report will appear on the right side.
//
// Additionally, you can toggle specific options in the Configure
// menu.

function main() {
  return 'Hello, World!';
}

main();/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// HTTP request - duas alternativas
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

//chama o express, que abre o servidor
var express = require('express');

// create a new express server 
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    // print a message when the server starts listening
    console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});


app.get('/home1', function (req,res) {
    http.get('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json', function (res2) {
        var body = '';
        res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res2.on('end', function () {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var cotacao = json["bovespa"]["cotacao"];
            var CotacaoDolar = json["dolar"]["cotacao"];
            var VariacaoDolar = json["dolar"]["variacao"];
            var CotacaoEuro = json["euro"]["cotacao"];
            var VariacaoEuro = json["euro"]["variacao"];
            var Atualizacao = json["atualizacao"];
   
   console.log('url', req.originalUrl);
   
   obj=req.query; 
   
   DolarUsuario=obj['dolar'];
   RealUsuario=Number(obj['dolar'])*CotacaoDolar;
   
   EuroUsuario=obj['euro'];
   RealUsuario2=Number(obj['euro'])*CotacaoEuro;
   
   if (VariacaoDolar<0) {
   recomend= "Recomenda-se, portanto, comprar dólares.";
   }
   
   else if (VariacaoDolar=0){
    recomend="";
   }
   
   else {
    recomend="Recomenda-se,portanto, vender dólares.";
      }
      
   if (VariacaoEuro<0) {
   recomend2= "Recomenda-se, portanto, comprar euros.";
   }
   
   else if (VariacaoEuro=0){
    recomend2="";
   }
   else {
    recomend2="Recomenda-se,portanto, vender euros.";
      }   
      
   res.render('cotacao_response.jade', {
                    'CotacaoDolar':CotacaoDolar,
      'VariacaoDolar':VariacaoDolar,
      'Atualizacao':Atualizacao,
      'RealUsuario':RealUsuario,
      'DolarUsuario':DolarUsuario,
      'CotacaoEuro':CotacaoEuro,
      'VariacaoEuro':VariacaoEuro,
      'RealUsuario2':RealUsuario2,
      'recomend':recomend,
      'recomend2':recomend2
      
            });
   var csv = require("fast-csv");

   csv
    .fromPath("Cambio.csv")
    .on("record", function(data){
     console.log(data);
    })
    .on("end", function(){
     console.log("done");
    });
   
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(body)` just before ` var json = JSON.parse(body);` ?

Answer (score 1):

The code did not work because it was missing views engine setup.
After adding the following lines after `var app = express();`:

```
// view engine setup
var path = require('path');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

and creating a sample `Cambio.csv` on the application root directory (same dir as `app.js`):

```
$ more Cambio.csv
mercado,cotacao,variacao
bovespa,1234,-2.3
dolar,3.777,0.23
euro,4.233,0.12
```

I run `node app.js` and point my browser to:

http://http://localhost:6006/home1

Output was:

```
$ node app.js
server starting on http://localhost:6006
url /home1
[ 'mercado', 'cotacao', 'variacao' ]
[ 'bovespa', '1234', '-2.3' ]
[ 'dolar', '3.777', '0.23' ]
[ 'euro', '4.233', '0.12' ]
```